# Package for fast spherical harmonic transform in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration, packages, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

[Mathematica's implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html) of the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) is, naturally, much faster than computing the discrete transform yourself using `Sum`.

The analog of the Fourier transform of a function `f[theta, phi]` on the unit sphere is an expansion in terms of spherical harmonics:

```
fHarmonics := Table[
   NIntegrate[
     Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, theta, phi]] f[theta, phi] Sin[theta],
     {theta, 0, pi}, {phi, 0, 2 pi}
   ],
   {m, -l, l}, {l, 0, lmax}
 ]
```

However, this is very slow, unsurprisingly.  Is there a package for Mathematica implementing the widely known algorithms ([ref 1](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/nfsft.php), [ref 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999185901895), [ref 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6522), [ref 4](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01261607)) for performing this transformation efficiently?

This was [asked without answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/KqxlSCNKjvg) in 2013 on Google Groups. [Jens Keiner's thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.8590&rep=rep1&type=pdf) claims to have implemented this in Mathematica, but I couldn't dig up the code.  (I've emailed Keiner and will update this question if he answers.)

Comment: `NIntegrate` is not so slow by itself, rather the bottleneck is in repeated evaluation of the function for each spherical harmonic. Therefore, a very simple solution is to precompute the function and the weights on a certain mesh once and for all. I typically use the Fibonacci integration (J H Hannay and J F Nye 2004 J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 37 11591) which is extremely easy to implement and which gives excellent accuracy if the order of `SphericalHarmonicY` is not too high. Thus, I advocate simplicity (no extra package is needed), although other methods could potentially be much faster.

Comment: @yarchik: Yes, if the function `f` is expensive to evaluate then pre-computation is useful.  (I had already implemented this using `FunctionInterpolation` on my machine, but didn't want to distract from the main question.)  However, even if we ignore the cost of computing `f`, the integration *is* slow by itself.  Likewise, the FFT is known to be much faster than computing a discrete Fourier transform using `Sum` even when access to the discrete function values is free; it is the addition and multiplication steps that are slow.

Comment: FYI It seems one of the authors of [a nonequispaced fast Fourier transform library](https://github.com/NFFT/nfft) is the same Jens Keiner. The lib is written in C, with some M. notebooks in tests folder.

Answer (score 13):

- I am aware that my answer would not be accepted because OP explicitly
  demanded a FFT-like method.
- I am aware of the fact that the method is not very fast either.
- However, it is so simple that I do this post to help benchmarking more advanced
  algorithms.
- I follow here the Fibonacci integration algorithm proposed by J. H. Hannay and J. F. Nye, [J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. **37** 11591 (2004)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/37/48/005).

---

### Mesh

At first, let us define a function to generate the mesh and corresponding weights. The accuracy depends on the number of points.

```
fMesh[n_] := Module[{fp, fn, dz, zj, θ, ϕ, w},
  fp = Fibonacci[n - 1];
  fn = Fibonacci[n];
  dz = 2/fn;
  Flatten[Table[
    zj = -1 + j dz;
    θ = ArcCos[zj + Sin[π zj]/π];
    ϕ = π j fp/fn; 
    w = π dz (1 + Cos[π zj]);
    {{θ, ϕ, w}, {θ, -ϕ, w}}, {j, 0, fn}], 1]
]
```

---

Plot a representative mesh (19th order)

```
v = Table[θ = k[[1]]; ϕ = k[[2]];
   x = Sin[ θ] Cos[ϕ];
   y = Sin[ θ] Sin[ϕ];
   z = Cos[ θ];
   {x, y, z}, {k, fMesh[19] // N}];
ListPointPlot3D[v, BoxRatios -> 1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

---

### Simplest application---normalization of $Y_{10}^9(\theta,\phi)$

Verify the normalization of a particular spherical harmonics

```
Sum[ θ = k[[1]]; ϕ = k[[2]]; w = k[[3]];
 w Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[10, 9, θ, ϕ] ] 
   SphericalHarmonicY[10, 9, θ, ϕ], {k, fMesh[15] // N}]
```

### Brute-force evaluation of many integrals

Use a *brute-force* approach to compute the integrals of two spherical harmonics. The output should be an identity matrix. The norm of its deviation from the Identity matrix will be our error measure.

```
lmx = 4;
ord = Flatten[Table[{l, m}, {l, 0, lmx}, {m, -l, l}], 1];
m[15] = fMesh[15] // N;
Timing[

 Norm[

  Table[{li, mi} = i; {lj, mj} = j;
    Sum[ θ = k[[1]]; ϕ = k[[2]]; w = k[[3]];
     w Conjugate[ SphericalHarmonicY[li, mi, θ, ϕ] ] 
       SphericalHarmonicY[lj, mj, θ, ϕ], {k, m[15]}], {i, ord}, {j, ord}] 

  -IdentityMatrix[Length[ord]]
  ]
 ]
```

`lmx`-maximal angular momentum, `ord`-list of `{l,m}` values. The computation takes around 4 seconds and yields quite precise results.

> {4.64707, 1.02165*10^-9}

---

### Matrix multiplication for speed

Now we do the same, however, we use the *matrix multiplication* in order to compute all the integrals at once.

```
Timing[

 fTab = Table[
   {li, mi} = i;
   θ = k[[1]]; ϕ = k[[2]]; w = k[[3]];
   w Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[li, mi, θ, ϕ]], 
    {k, m[15]}, {i, ord}];

 yTab = Table[
   {li, mi} = i;
   θ = k[[1]]; ϕ = k[[2]]; w = k[[3]];
   SphericalHarmonicY[li, mi, θ, ϕ], 
   {k, m[15]}, {i, ord}];

Norm[Transpose[fTab].yTab - IdentityMatrix[Length[ord]]]
 ]
```

The result is identical, however, the computation is `>10` times faster

> {0.257956, 1.02165*10^-9}

Comment: Useful, thanks!

Comment: It works well. Thanks.

Comment: @tanghe2014 You are welcome, happy it was helpful.

Comment: @yarchik The mesh duplication implemented here differs from the one described by Hannay & Nye. On the line `{{θ, ϕ, w}, {θ, -ϕ, w}}`, the duplication by Hannay & Nye puts the second mesh at `{{θ, ϕ, w}, {θ, ϕ + π, w}}`, i.e., rotated by $\pi$ from the first one about the $z$ axis, instead of reflected on the $xz$ plane. The reflected version adds some anisotropy to the mesh; this isn't terrible (as shown by your benchmarks), but it does open the question on whether the altered duplication degrades the performance for integrands with higher anisotropy than the $Y_{lm}$s.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Interesting observation. I know that you posted a question on this topic. Maybe you can answer your own question and demonstrate the superiority of the Hannay and Nye choice.

Comment: @yarchik I asked a question because I am occupied with physics; I unfortunately do not have time to benchmark numerical integration strategies, let alone investigate variations without a clear origin or reason. Thank you for pointing me to your (fixable) implementation of the Hannay & Nye algorithm, which will probably be the final choice. I was simply pointing out that the code presented here differs from the published version and therefore does not benefit from the guarantees the pre-existing published work offers.