# Are there any dedicated built-in methods to NIntegrate over the unit sphere or the 3D rotational group?

Tags: numerical-integration, rotation

As part of a molecular-physics calculation, I need to perform an integral to find the average of a certain function over all the possible orientations of the molecule,
$$
\langle f(\mathbf v)\rangle = \int_{R\in\mathrm{SO}(3)} f(R\mathbf v) \:\mathrm dR
$$
To some extent, it is relatively easy to find clear ways to do this in Mathematica: the Haar measure in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is cleanly expressed in terms of the Euler angles, and these are then easy to translate to $R$ using [`EulerMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerMatrix.html), so one can use something like

```
NIntegrate[
 f[EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}] . v] 1/8 Sin[β]
 , {α, -π, π}, {β, -(π/2), π/2}, {γ, π, π}]
```

However, this approach doesn't really "know" anything about the structure of the rotation group, and it looks liable to choose some sub-optimal sampling strategies that over-sample the regions where the Euler-angle coordinate mapping is singular.

(In case a specific example is useful, $f(\mathbf v)$ can be chosen to be e.g. $f(\mathbf v) = \left((\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf v)^2+(\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf v)^2\right)^p$ for suitable semi-random $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$ and $p$.)

Having a look at the literature, there seems to be a clear consensus that the optimal way to do this is to decompose $\mathrm{SO}(3) \cong \mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^1$ (i.e., use the angle-axis representation used by [`RotationMatrix[θ,w]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html)) and then use

- some simple 1D integrator for the $\mathbb S^1$ factor, and
- a dedicated spherical quadratures for the integration over the rotation-axis orientation in $\mathbb S^2$.

As I understand it, the leading spherical quadrature used for the second factor is the [Lebedev quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebedev_quadrature), which is symmetric under the octahedral group and is chosen to integrate, exactly, the spherical harmonics up to a given order.

So, on to my questions:

- Is there an existing (built-in, or pre-built package) way to use Lebedev quadratures in Mathematica?
- If not, is there an existing implementation that can be adapted for this?
- Alternatively, is there any way to inform `NIntegrate` about this structure and make it exploit it?
- Or can this be ignored by suitable settings for `NIntegrate` that will make it choose a close-to-optimal integration strategy?

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171856/9469). This is not a Lebedev quadrature, but still one quite efficient way to integrate over $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could help? [51744/46237](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51744/46237)